# Skipping empty cells when using an Index/Match formula

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I need to read out information from a database using the Index and Match formula. I have 1 criteria giving away the row and 2 criterias giving away the columb. This is the formula that I am using:

`{=INDEX($A$1:$E$7,MATCH(A13,$A$1:$A$7,0),MATCH($B$11&$B$12,$1:$1&$2:$2,0))}`

Some entries in the database are empty. When the index formula hits such a blank entry, it returns zero. How can I make the Index formula search on until it finds an entry which has text in it?

Here you can see the data I use and the output I get:

[image: Data and Output]

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Is there always only one number per company, it just may be in another row?

Comment: Exactly, there is always one number per company, but the company might show 2 times, with the first entry being blank.

Answer (score 0):

B13 ↓

```
=VLOOKUP(A13,A:E,(B$12-2014)*2+(B$11="Summer"),)
```